# What is causing the "Failed to create the hard disk storage" when creating the virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, external-hard-drive

I am installing the virtual machine on an external hard drive.
Here is my error.

> Failed to create the hard disk storage D:\VirtualBox VMs\macOS Catalina\macOS Catalina.vmdk.
>
> Could not create the medium storage unit 'D:\VirtualBox VMs\macOS Catalina\macOS Catalina.vmdk'.
>
> VMDK: could not set size of new file 'D:\VirtualBox VMs\macOS Catalina\macOS Catalina-f001.vmdk' (VERR_TIMEOUT).
>
> Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
> Component: MediumWrap
> Interface: IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}

I ran winsat and these were the results.

> Running: Feature Enumeration ''
>
> Run Time 00:00:00.00
>
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive d -ran -read'
>
> Run Time 00:00:14.20
>
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive d -seq -read'
>
> Run Time 00:00:26.66
>
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive d -seq -write'
>
> Run Time 00:00:30.30
>
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive d -flush -seq'
>
> Run Time 00:00:10.58
>
> Running: Storage Assessment '-drive d -flush -ran'
>
> Run Time 00:00:10.48
>
> Dshow Video Encode Time                      0.00000 s
>
> Dshow Video Decode Time                      0.00000 s
>
> Media Foundation Decode Time                 0.00000 s
>
> Disk  Random 16.0 Read                       1.20 MB/s          3.4
>
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Read                   27.25 MB/s          4.1
>
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write                  23.66 MB/s          3.9
>
> Average Read Time with Sequential Writes     9.671 ms          4.6
>
> Latency: 95th Percentile                     19.696 ms          4.6
>
> Latency: Maximum                             46.684 ms          7.9
>
> Average Read Time with Random Writes         10.100 ms          4.5
>
> Total Run Time 00:01:41.67

Comment: Is there enough free space on that drive? Does the folder `D:\VirtualBox VMs\macOS Catalina` exist? Is the disk fast enough?

Comment: Also, it is a grey area whether making a MAC OS is supported.

Comment: @EugenRieck About 650 GB of free space of which I am allocating 100GB to the Virtual machine, and yes the folder `D:\VirtualBox VMs\macOS Catalina` exists.

Comment: And is the disk fast enough? The error message seems to suggest VMDK creation times out. For VMDK format with full provisioning you shouldn't be below 100MB/s.

Comment: Check the SMART data of the disk for write errors. You might have a bad sector.

Comment: @harrymc I ran CrystalDiskInfo and the SMART status was `Good`.